# Ranger: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ranger'

Tags: arch-linux, python, pacman, pip, ranger

I have `ranger` on Arch linux. When I try to run it throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ranger", line 35, in <module>
    import ranger  # NOQA pylint: disable=import-self,wrong-import-position
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ranger'
```

How can I fix it ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by uninstalling it by pip and yay:

```
pip uninstall ranger
yay -R ranger
```

and installed ranger again using:

```
yay -S ranger-git
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing an additional `pip` package:

```
pip install ranger-fm
```